# Search Query in a SubForm, how to reference

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

Forgive me if this is basic. I am trying to learn and build a sort of "portal" for my office.
Need help with Access.

Overview: I have a few forms build out. The main form has multiple subforms. One one Subform I want to have a search bar for searching contacts.

Troubleshooting so far: I created a separate form all on its own. Created a Query for my "contacts" table. Then used a text box in my form to serve as the search bar. This works great. I am able to search my entire table and have it update in my list box.
The Criteria for the query is Like " * " & [Forms]![ContactSearch]![SearchBox] & " * "

Issue: When I try to recreate my efforts to one of the subforms, I cannot get it to work. My list box will show all the contacts from the table, but the text box for seaching will not work.

What I think my problem is, is I do not know the syntax to reference my searchbox in the subform.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How can I verify the correct name to use for the subform?

Answer (score 0):

It will be:

```
[Forms]![ContactSearch]![NameOfTheSubformControl].Form![SearchBox]
```

Please note, that `NameOfTheSubformControl` may differ from the name of the form used as a subform.